# Use tar to extract files from an archive with an unknown name

Tags: windows, cmd, tar

I would like to use `tar` (on Windows) in a command line to extract files from an archive, that has a variable name, like `*-archive.zip`, that I don't know beforehand. I haven't found a way to use a wildcard for the targeted archive name, is there an option to do that ?

I have tried things like `tar -xf "*-archive.zip"`, but it searches for a file with the same exact name, not the pattern.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper solution is (as Mofi suggested) :

```
for %I in (*-archive.zip) do tar.exe -xf "%I"
```

But what I ended up doing is switching to PowerShell, and ditching `tar` that cannot handle PowerShell pipes. The final command is :

```
Get-ChildItem -Name -Filter *-archive.zip | Expand-Archive
```

It works provided there is only one file matching the pattern in the current working folder.

Comment: That PowerShell command line cannot be used in a Windows Command Prompt window as tagged in the question. It also does not use `tar` at all. A Windows Command Prompt solution would be `for %I in (*-archive.zip) do tar.exe -xf "%I"` which instructs `cmd.exe` to search in current directory for files matching the wildcard pattern `*-archive.zip` and for each found file search in file system using the environment variables `PATH` and `PATHEXT` for a file with name `tar.exe` and on found at all run it with `-xf` as first argument and the current ZIP file name as second argument.

Answer (score 0):

Use 'tar --wildcards ...' (works at least with tar 1.33). Example:

```
╰─➤ $ tar --wildcards -tvf /home/johndoe/.cpan/sources/authors/id/T/TO/TODDR/XML-Parser-2.44.tar.gz '*enc'
-rw-r--r-- todd/staff    40706 2014-12-11 07:51 XML-Parser-2.44/Parser/Encodings/big5.enc
-rw-r--r-- todd/staff    45802 2014-12-11 07:51 XML-Parser-2.44/Parser/Encodings/euc-kr.enc
-rw-r--r-- todd/staff     1072 2014-12-11 07:51 XML-Parser-2.44/Parser/Encodings/ibm866.enc
...
```

Comment: Could you please submit an answer which suits the tags [[tag:windows]] and [[tag:cmd]], not just something which matches the tag [[tag:tar]].

Comment: There is no `--wildcards` option on Windows, and even if there were, it matches files **inside** the archive, and not the name of the archive itself.